# Как получить доступ к переменным "Windows Form С++"

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Имеется форма Windows на с++.
Хочу работать в отдельном потоке с datagridview1(добавлять, удалять строки и т.д.).
Как можно с ним работать в **отдельном потоке**, т.к. основной поток занят тем, что показывает эту самую форму и обрабатывает действия пользователя.
В чем возникает проблема: в том, что используя Test::Server::datagridview1 компилировщик ругается, что нельзя обращаться к нестатическому обьекту. Пробовал так: Test::Server Server; Server.datagridview->Rows->Add(); Получалось. Но на моей форме ни каких изменений не было(Это в принципе логично, т.к. по сути я создавал новый экземляр формы, но ни где его не показывал).
Пробовал dataGridView1 объявлять как static, но тогда компилировщик ругается на то, что работаю не в основном потоке.  Вот пример файла Server.h:

```
public ref class Server : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
        {
        public:
            Server(void)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                //
                //TODO: добавьте код конструктора
                //
            }

        protected:
            /// <summary>
            /// Освободить все используемые ресурсы.
            /// </summary>
            ~Server()
            {
                if (components)
                {
                    delete components;
                }
            }

        private: System::Windows::Forms::BindingSource^  bindingSource1;
        public: System::Windows::Forms::DataGridView^  dataGridView1;
        ...
```

А вот файл MyForm.cpp:

```
#include "Server.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Test::Server Server;
    Application::Run(%Server);
    return 0;
}
void ReceivePackets(void *arg)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Sleep(500);
        Address sender;
        unsigned char buffer[256];
        int bytes_read =
            sock.Receive(sender,
                buffer,
                sizeof(buffer));
        if (bytes_read <= 0)
            continue;
        const char* packet_data = (const char*)buffer;
        //Далее был бы код, как я запихиваю packet_data в datagridview1
    }
}

void checkNews()
{
    _beginthread(ReceivePackets, 0, NULL);
}

System::Void Test::Server::Server_Load(System::Object ^ sender, System::EventArgs ^ e)
{
    checkNews();
    return System::Void();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С формами и их контролами можно работать только с того потока на котором их создали. Другие потоки должны использовать [`Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Пример самый простенький можно? В интернете найти не могу.

Comment: Invoke использовать в MyForm.cpp не получается